# How to Show An Element Above It's Previous Element Vuetify

Tags: html, css, user-interface, vuetify.js, user-experience

I want to overlap elements of a component obove another component. It is like bellow image:

[image]

I tried by setting

> class="mt-n16"

as css styling in Vuetify. But its showing hidden as bellow:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a code example, so we can see the isolated issue. One option would be creating a codepen with just the components involved.

Comment: I am new to ui/ux. Can you please tell me how to design as the above image?

Comment: Please copy the HTML of the image above and the row of images below.